# Configuration to maintain the original formatting of the HTML document in the Solr results?

Tags: html, apache, solr

I am using Apache Solr. I have to retain the HTML format, with all the original HTML tags, in Solr's returned results. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set stored=true for any text oriented field (TextField, StrField) you will be able to retrieve it in the original format. Indexing/tokenizing/filtering will not impact the retrieved field. Syntax is:

```
<field name="examplestringfieldstored" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Comment: I tried this but have a doubt. Here i used following line in schema.xml <field name="filed1" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> but what i need to set for this filed 'filed1' while indexing? Please advise.